# PHP MySQL Injection Protection

Tags: php, mysql, urlencode, code-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I have the following function I call when using variables passed from another page. My question is, can I add urlencode information to this and have a single function I use, or is it best to have separate functions for variables I pass information through the address bar vs. a hidden form field?

I am not using PDO, and I typecast when possible.

```
function checkInput($value) {
// Stripslashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())

// Stripslashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$value = stripslashes($value);
}

// Quote if not a number
{
$value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
return $value;
}
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli also supports prepared statements. If mysqli isn't available, there's always systems like PEAR DB that offers prepared statements as well.

Comment: Yup, there's no reason not to use prepared statements.  The classic `mysql_*` functions should be considered deprecated.  They're old tech that have far better modern counterparts.

Comment: Sometimes, people don't have a choice of which technology stack they work on. Mysqli might not be enabled either, in which case, the only option is mysql_*. :)